# Action with double [FromBody] parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a problem with passing 2 parameters to my `[HttpPut]` method. They are both marked with `[FromBody]` attribute and they are both nulls when I test that method with Postman. Controller reacts correctly by letting me into the method but i don't know how to write a correct JSON body to get correct response. I don't know if that's the right way of passing 2 parameters marked by `[FromBody]` or if it's even possible/allowed. In general I want to update my `BitPosition` object by passing an old one and swapping it to a new one. Can you help ?

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateBitPosition([FromBody]BitPosition oldBitPosition, [FromBody]BitPosition newBitPosition)
{
    if (oldBitPosition == null || newBitPosition == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    try
    {
        var bitPositionToUpdate = await _context.BitPositions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(bp => bp.IDPermission == oldBitPosition.IDPermission &&
                                                                                        bp.Position == oldBitPosition.Position);

        if (bitPositionToUpdate == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        bitPositionToUpdate.IDPermission = newBitPosition.IDPermission;
        bitPositionToUpdate.Position = newBitPosition.Position;

        _context.BitPositions.Update(bitPositionToUpdate);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return new NoContentResult();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Helpers.ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex);
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi .. can your WRAP your 2 objects in one? ..so somthing like: public class BitVM{ public BitPosition oldBitPosition{get; set;}, public BitPosition newBitPosition {get; set;} } .... and then pass it as payload of your HttPut method? like ([FromBody]BitVM bit)

Comment: FromBody can only be used once in action parameters. As already suggested you would need to merge the two models into one root model to allow the models to bind correctly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#binding-formatted-data-from-the-request-body

Comment: read the docs first before you post a question please

Comment: My bad. Thanks for pointing me the solution in docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#binding-formatted-data-from-the-request-body)

> "There can be at most one parameter per action decorated with [FromBody]"

So, I suggest you to merge the objects like this;

```
public class MergedBitPosition
{
    public BitPosition OldBitPosition { get; set; }

    public BitPosition NewBitPosition { get; set; }
}
```

And the method looks like;

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateBitPosition([FromBody]MergedBitPosition mergedBitPosition)
```

Sample Json request should be like this;

```
{
   "OldBitPosition":{
      "IdPermission":8,
      "Position":1
   },
   "NewBitPosition":{
      "IdPermission":8,
      "Position":5
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. How would JSON example look like for `MergedBitPosition`class ? I'm trying this : 
`[
 "OldBitPosition" :
    {
        "IdPermission": 8,
        "Position": 1
    }

 "NewBitPosition" :
    {
        "IdPermission": 8,
        "Position": 5
    }
]`
but it doesn't work.