# Getting both SimpleJsonPatchDocument and JSON from body

Tags: c#, .net-core

My PATCH looks like this:

```
public IActionResult Patch(Guid id, [FromBody] SimpleJsonPatchDocument<Foo> patch)
{
   var item = Get(id);

   ...
   ...
   ...

   patch.ApplyTo(item);

   ...
   ...

   return Ok(item);
}
```

I'd like to make use of the actual JObject/JSON that's coming in through the request's body in addition to the `SimpleJsonPatchDocument`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753014/action-with-double-frombody-parameters) question, there can be at most one parameter per action decorated with `[FromBody]`, so I can't do something like this:

```
public IActionResult Patch(Guid id, [FromBody] SimpleJsonPatchDocument<Foo> patch, 
[FromBody] JObject json)
{
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

What are my options?

Ideally I'd like to be able to get the `JObject` from the body of the request, and then convert it to a `SimpleJsonPatchDocument` within the controller.

Comment: You are receiving one json string which contains both classes (i guess) in that case create a class with a proprty for each class (as the json is) and use that class as the parameter.

Comment: @MrZach that's not the case! The json string I am receiving just contains the properties and values that need to be changed, but I want to store that json string somewhere, in addition to doing the PATCH.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both model binding for `SimpleJsonPatchDocument<Foo> patch` parameter and get raw json from request body, then you have to read request stream twice. You cannot do that after model binding happened, because request body stream will be disposed at that time. So, you can get raw body only before model binding. Also you should ensure that stream is not disposed and stream position is set to the beginning (thus model binding can read request body later).

You can use `TypeFilterAttribute` or `IAuthorizationFilter` attribute (both can process the request before model binding):

```
public class RawBodyAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        request.EnableBuffering(); // you cannot seek original request stream

        // make sure stream is not disposed
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // simplest way to pass body value to controller
            context.HttpContext.Items.Add("Body", body);
            request.Body.Position = 0; // now model binder can read stream again
        }
    }
}
```

Now just add this attribute to any action where you need the raw body, and you will get it from HttpContext items:

```
[RawBody]
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
public IActionResult Patch(Guid id, [FromBody] SimpleJsonPatchDocument<Foo> patch)
{
   var item = Get(id);
   patch.ApplyTo(item);

   var json = JObject.Parse((string)Request.HttpContext.Items["Body"]);

   return Ok(item);
}
```

Comment: But then, how do I get the `SimpleJsonPatchDocument<Foo> patch`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you have mentioned, for a PUT/POST/PATCH etc, there can be an only a single request body. What you can do is create a custom DTO that wraps around your parameters and pass it along.

```
public class CustomDto
{
    public SimpleJsonPatchDocument<Foo> Patch { get; set; }
    public JObject<Foo> Json { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Patch(Guid id, [FromBody] CustomDto data)
{
   // TODO: Access properties of data
   // data.Patch
   // data.Json
   // etc.
}
```

Comment: thanks! Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question but I am not sending the JsonPatchDocument in the request body, I am just sending data that needs to be changed and that's being converted into a `SimpleJsonPatchDocument` automatically in the server. Ideally, I'd like to conserve the JSON that came through the request, and also convert that to a `SimpleJsonPatchDocument` on the server.